Software to recover corrupted mp4 videos
I have some collections of old films, downloaded with torrent, half of them seems corrupted because when I try to open one of them (with vlc or mediaplayer) it starts but I can't navigate it and the image seems broken.
Because films are some GB I am searching an offline tool but I can try also online if it works

This depends on what type of corruption occurred, it is possible that it is file degradation at the file system level or storage media degradation, in which case it has nothing to do with video reparation. You may instead need a file recovery software or even a data recovery expert.
